# Ubuntu Kernel swap

Tags: kernel, motherboard

I have been having a lot of trouble getting Ubuntu to install on my mother board. Fedora however does install. I will use Fedora if I have to but I prefer Ubuntu for many reasons. I was wondering if it is possible to switch the Fedora and Ubuntu kernels. I've never done anything with kernels before and am not even sure if this would help but I don't want to not ask just in case it does. Also, would installing things like graphics card drivers install the same as in Ubuntu or the Fedora way. I don't think the kernel would change this but I just wanna be sure. Thanks for any help. Also the things that don't work in Ubuntu on my motherboard are the Ethernet and the 3.0 usb. the graphics don't work either but i figured out how to fix that problem.

Comment: Perhaps if you were to explain the trouble you are having installing Ubuntu we could assist you with that. for instance the output of `sudo lshw -C network` might give us some insight into the problem you are having with Ethernet. `lsusb -t` would provide some clues regarding your USB 3.0 problems

Comment: would i do this after the install or while i am installing it?

Comment: You can complete the commands in a terminal booting live prior to installation or after the 1st is a listing of network class hardware and the 2nd a tree view of your USB hardware. The end result should be identical.

Comment: I installed 16.04 beta and am still having the same problems. i ran the commands, should i just copy and paste the output here as a comment?

Comment: 16.04 is not yet supported as it is in beta. 14.04 is a long term support release and I recommend it. Asking questions about 16.04 before it's release date will result in your question being tossed as off-topic.  the command `ubuntu-support-status` will shed some light in the support status of your current system and to review previous versions and there status look here: http://www.ubuntu.com/info/release-end-of-life

Answer (score 1):

The Fedora kernel is unlikely to work well with Ubuntu as the kernels are not in sync between the distros and each distro has applied distro specific patches such as apparmor in Ubuntu and Selinux in Fedora.

You are probably better off compiling a custom kernel from the ubuntu repositories using the ubuntu patches.

Better, what problem are you having with which ubuntu kernel ?

Comment: I have tried 14.04, 14.10, 15.04, and 15.10. none of these releases work. i think i have also tried 12.04 but im not sure. im having the same problems as i stated in the question with all these releases.

Comment: and what fedora kernel ?

Comment: I just downloaded the lastet fedora version. this was like a month ago. i don't know if they updated it recently.

Comment: fedora is using 4.4.2-301.fc23.x86_64 which is roughly xenial inux-image-4.4.0-8-generic so 16.04 beta

Comment: how would I get 16.04 beta?

Comment: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

Comment: Sweet, thanks, I'll look into this later in the week. Thanks again.